# Python's itertools.product in C

Tags: c, cartesian-product

There is a function in Python which runs this way:

```
itertools.product("abc", repeat = 2)
```

returns the following:

```
("a", "a")
("a", "b")
("a", "c")
("b", "a")
("b", "b")
("b", "c")
("c", "a")
("c", "b")
("c", "c")
```

Changing the repeat variable will change how many items come back in a tuple.
How can this be written in C to return an array of arrays of chars? (an array of strings)

UPDATE: I now have this function I wrote:

```
void cartesian(char *a, int al, char *b, int bl){
    int i, j;
    char c[al * bl][2];
    for(i = 0; i < al; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < bl; j++){
            c[(i * bl) + j][0] = *(a + i);
            c[(i * bl) + j][1] = *(b + j);
            printf("%c%c\n", *(a + i), *(b + j));
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char a[] = "abc";
    char b[] = "ab";
    cartesian(a, strlen(a), b, strlen(b));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change this function so it can take in an array of of arrays of char and make the cartesian product? The arrays could contain any number of chars and there could be any number of arrays

The function should look like:

```
void cartesian(char *a, int l){
    /*Do cartesian*/
}
```

Example array:

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c', '\0'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', '\0'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', '\0']
]
```

(nulls included to work out length of arrays)
should produce

```
[
    ['a', 'a', 'a'],
    ['a', 'a', 'b'],
    ['a', 'a', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'a'],
    ['a', 'b', 'b'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'c', 'a'],
    ['a', 'c', 'b'],
    ['a', 'c', 'c'],
    ['b', 'a', 'a'],
    ['b', 'a', 'b'],
    ['b', 'a', 'c'],
    ['b', 'b', 'a'],
    ['b', 'b', 'b'],
    ['b', 'b', 'c'],
    ['b', 'c', 'a'],
    ['b', 'c', 'b'],
    ['b', 'c', 'c'],
    ['c', 'a', 'a'],
    ['c', 'a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'a', 'c'],
    ['c', 'b', 'a'],
    ['c', 'b', 'b'],
    ['c', 'b', 'c'],
    ['c', 'c', 'a'],
    ['c', 'c', 'b'],
    ['c', 'c', 'c'],
]
```

Comment: The *Python* version is written in C: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1804, with the heavy lifting done in the `product_next` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a C implementation of cartesian product according to your specification. Note though that the argument is `char **a`, not `char *a` as it's an array of strings.

This is a variation on a [previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4008399/325117)

```
    void cartesian(char **a, unsigned int l)
    {
        unsigned int *indices = calloc(l, sizeof(int));
        unsigned int changed;
        do {
            unsigned int finished = 0;
            unsigned int i;
            changed = 0;
            /* Print the current tuple */
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                putchar(a[i][indices[i]]);
            }
            putchar('\n');
            /* Loop over the arrays in reverse order */
            for (i = l - 1; !changed && !finished; i--) {
                /* Increment */
                indices[i]++;
                if (a[i][indices[i]]) {
                    /* We moved to the next character */
                    changed = 1;
                }
                else {
                    /* End of string, so roll over */
                    indices[i] = 0;
                }
                finished = i == 0;
            }
        } while (changed);
        free(indices);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The following C program creates all possible permutations of "abc".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
   int i;
   if (l == r)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
       for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
       {
          swap((a+l), (a+i));
          permute(a, l+1, r);
          swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "abc";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Probably there is an even faster way to code this. Runtime O(n*n!). I only noticed later that you were requesting the cartesian product. But several stack overflow entries can be found with similar requests. [Generate the Cartesian Product of 2 vector<string>s In-Place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883315/generate-the-cartesian-product-of-2-vectorstrings-in-place)

Comment: The OP wants the cartesian product, not permutations.

Comment: I was not sure what he is actually trying to achieve therefore I posted the code anyway.

Comment: also can this be done iteratively, rather than recursively?

Comment: For a permutation algorithm probably not. But the cartesian product certainly. That's why I also provided a link to the C++ Code of the same problem. If you know C it should be pretty easy to follow up.